# Ubuntu 16.04 instalation on External HDD of 1TB

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, external-hdd

After following couple of tutorials found on askubuntu, I tried to install Ubuntu 16.04 on Seagate Maxtor 1TB external hard disk.

I partition the hard disk using gParted to use GPT table, instead of MBR.

When running the installation I encounter the following problem.

```
The partition /dev/sdb3 assigned to / starts at an offset of 2048 bytes from the minimum alignment for this disk, which may lead to very poor performance.

Since you are formatting this partition, you should correct this problem now by realigning the partition, as it will be difficult to change later.

To do this, go back to the main partitioning menu, delete the partition, and recreate it in the same position with the same settings. This will cause the partition to start at a point best suited for this disk.
```

The partition are created correctly, also clicking the **continue** just close the dialog popup and nothing happens.

Strange thing I notice is that, at the beginning there are 33MB of unallocated disk space. Usually this number is 1MB on my main HDD.

Just to notice, this is not my first time installing Linux, but it is my first time encountering this message.

Edit: Image upload.
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you totally erased drive? Seagates have been known to have issues, and I think it is proprietary Windows drivers in a hidden partition. That is probably the 33MB you are seeing.

Comment: I used gparted several times to delete the partition and create new ones, I even changed the partition table. I even started the installation with 1TB of unallocated size.

Comment: Also I want to know if this problem is ubuntu related, or also every other distribution have similar problems.

Comment: Unless you are using a very old gparted it should auto align all partitions. Not sure then why the issue. Also bios_grub only needs to be 1 or 2MB unformatted. I typically only allocate 25GB for /, but have all data normally in /home in a separate /mnt/data partition. But 25GB should also be ok, if you have a separate /home.  What happens if you start partitions at beginning of drive. Should show 0 sectors before first partition when creating it. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace